# "OSError: Starting path not found" when using Selenium webdriver manager for the first time in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set up Selenium 4 in Python for the first time on my Windows 10 PC. I want to be able to manipulate a browser session locally with login.

- I updated local Python 3 to the latest release 3.11.3
- I installed the latest stable Selenium release 4.9.0 by downloading the files manually and then running `setup.py`
- I installed the latest Webdriver-mananger release 4.9.0 by downloading the files manually and then running `setup.py`
- I updated the local ChromeDriver
- I created an empty `.env` file in my working directory.
- I created a `requirements.txt` file with a single line `selenium==4.9.0` as instructed by [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/). (Honestly, I don't really know how the requirements file works.)
- I added the directory containing Chrome driver to environment variable %PATH%

Next, I created a `test.py` file in the working directory as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But upon running the file with `python test.py` where `python` is `DOSKEY`'d to the Python executable, I received the "OSError: Starting path not found" error as follows.

Yet, the very same line by itself `print(find_dotenv())` and without input with `from dotenv import find_dotenv` outputs the full path `...\.env` seemingly successfully. (I am not sure how to find out how the `.egg` file interacts with `find_dotenv()`.)

What can I do to get Selenium running?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager-3.8.6-py3.11.egg\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager-3.8.6-py3.11.egg\webdriver_manager\core\download_manager.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager-3.8.6-py3.11.egg\webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager-3.8.6-py3.11.egg\webdriver_manager\core\config.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\dotenv\main.py", line 336, in load_dotenv
    dotenv_path = find_dotenv()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\dotenv\main.py", line 300, in find_dotenv
    for dirname in _walk_to_root(path):
  File "C:\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\python_dotenv-1.0.0-py3.11.egg\dotenv\main.py", line 257, in _walk_to_root
    raise IOError('Starting path not found')
```

Comment: Are you quite sure you're running Python 3.11?  Because the traceback clearly shows you are running Python 3.8.

Comment: @TimRoberts: I am not. (Some path names are from 3.8 times though.) I'll check

Comment: @TimRoberts: Turns out I didn't have the update cuz I didn't change installation paths. But I repeated the steps and still get the same error -- albeit with shorter trace. I updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE, or are you starting it from a command line?  If you check in the source, this indicates that the path where it STARTED looking is not a real path.

Comment: @TimRoberts: cmd. What do you mean not a real path? I thought `IOError` is raised when `.env` file is not found and so I created an empty `.env` file in the working directory.

Comment: No, it doesn't say that `.env` was not found.  That's a different error.  It says the "starting path was not found".  You can go look up the source code to see what that means.  It tries to follow the chain of module imports to find the path of the outermost source file, and then it searches each directory from there upwards to find `.env`.  In this case, the directory it started at wasn't found.  Are you running this in an IDE?  You didn't answer that.

Comment: @TimRoberts" I am not running in an IDE but in cmd. In the Python 3.8 versions of the packages, the trace gave line numbers so I looked and the function that throws the error outputs the directory of the `.env` file in working directory when I run the same function in my own file. What do you mean by the outermost source file?

Comment: Are you literally typing `python test.py`, so that the "current directory" is where the script is?  If you do `import os` / `print(os.getcwd())` as the first lines, does it print something sensible?  There aren't a lot of ways for this to go wrong.  BTW, `requirements.txt` is only required if you intend to create an executable from this.